# Problem with ceil function in math module

Tags: python, math, ceil

by performing the following calculation

```
p=math.ceil(57050*1.12)
```

I am receiving 63897. However other tools (such as Excel) deliver 63896.

I need to use ceil (round up), because the procedure is part of a larger model, where I cannot make an exeption this specific value (57050).
The problem is that I need to import a current model from Excel into Python and it is very important that all calculations deliver the same values.

I was wondering if there is a way to adjust the precision of "ceil" by e.g. 10 decimals.
How can I adjust it, or what else can I do, that is not so severe, so that it is not going to create problems for other values?

Expected results:
63896

Actual results:
63897

Comment: Are you familiar with [the limitations of floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)? Have you considered using a different way to handle the numbers, such as the `decimal` standard library module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, if you want to make only the first 10 decimal places relevant, you could do something like the following:

```
def ceil(n):
    return math.ceil(int(n*10**10)/10**10)
```

Comment: The answer solved my problem. Thanks for that. @ThierryLathuille I not sure what you mean, but I am interested. I have 40 values that pass the function and they were all rounded up in the same way Excel also did it. So I am basically fine. Do you think this approach will cause other problems in future?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille I just answered the following question:
`I was wondering if there is a way to adjust the precision of "ceil" by e.g. 10 decimals. How can I adjust it, or what else can I do, that is not so severe, so that it is not going to create problems for other values?`
And the function I provided above does exactly that.